# Why does my wifi not automatically reconnect to prefered networks?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, wi-fi

I've got a San Francisco handset running 2.1.

I've configured it to connect to my wifi network at home. If I go out of range, or reboot the phone, it fails to re-connect automatically and I have to manually go thru the settings, disable wireless, then enable it for it to re-attach itself to my network

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Might be related to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2408/how-can-i-configure-my-phone-to-automatically-connect-to-remembered-wifi-networks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Power Control widget (available by default in Android 2.1+ for most phones) or a similar wi-fi toggle app to your home screen. (Long press on the home screen, Widget, Power Control.) That usually fixes it for me.